# Add proxy and port in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible set a proxy and port in VS 2022? I mean configuring VS just like Mozilla Firefox to use the local SSH tunnel.( where to add 127.0.0.1:myport ??)
In hell Iran everything is filtered and I can't download any nuget package inside Visual Studio.